# Scanner keeps on reading and repeats reading file

Tags: java, file, file-io, infinite

im writing my method to read a small file using scanner. at first i was doing it with a larger file but it was not working so i tested it with a small file and it still doesnt work. My file has the following lines..

```
1,0,.
5,1,.
10,2,.
```

my code is

```
    try
    {
        Scanner mapScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
        while(mapScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] parts = mapScanner.nextLine().split(",");
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n",parts[0],parts[1],parts[2]);
        }
        mapScanner.close();
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and when i run the program i get...

```
1 0 .
5 1 .
10 2 .
1 0 .
5 1 .
10 2 .
```

forever until i terminate the program. I dont understand the issue here, whether i use `hasNext` or `hasnextLine` the end of the file isnt detected.

EDIT whole code for the class, whole file are the 3 lines given above

```
public class FileHandler {
    private char[][] fileMapArray;

    public char[][] loadMap(){
        fileMapArray = new char[36][54];
        int column;
        int row;
        char symbol;
        File myFile = new File("/home/issac/NetBeansProjects/HWK2/src/main/simpleNot.map.txt");
        try
        {
            Scanner mapScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
            while(mapScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] parts = mapScanner.nextLine().split(",");
                System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n",parts[0],parts[1],parts[2]);
            }
            mapScanner.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return fileMapArray;    
    }

    public FileHandler() {
    }


}
```

Comment: I can only imagine there's a loop somewhere outside this code that is running multiple times.  The code you've posted will terminate at the end of the file.  Can you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that replicates this so we can run it?  You'll likely find your bug while trying to do so.

Comment: added, the code and in my main class i simply have a statement that calls this method once,

Comment: Without a `main` method, you don't have an SSCCE.  As is, what you've posted will still terminate at the end of the file; something outside of this code is looping.  Either that, or your operating system / Java install is deeply borked, but that's less likely.

Comment: The idea of an SSCCE is to remove the irrelevant parts of the code you're working on and create a runnable demo we can run and see for ourselves.  If you start from scratch and put your `try` block in a `main` method by itself, it should terminate.  If it does, it confirms that something else is looping.  If it doesn't, it confirms the bug is inside your posted code (which is highly unlikely).